# Get windowId from inspected Window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In a custom DevTools panel, I can use:

```
const tabId = chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId;
```

but looking at the docs, I can't figure out how to get the window id from chrome.devtools...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow

is there a way to get the windowId, as well as the tabId?

Comment: Simply use chrome.tabs.get with that tabId, which will give you the entire tab object with windowId property.

Comment: `chrome.tabs` is undefined in a content script, does it work in devtools page?

Comment: It's not clear from your question how it's related to the content script. In the worst case you'll have to obtain that data in a background script and pass back via messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm `chrome.tabs` appears to be undefined in both the content script and the devtools page, if that makes sense, so what you suggested won't work unfortunately tmk...I have the "tabs" permission in case you were wondering

Comment: Well then use the background page.

Comment: yeah, kinda weird, but I guess that's the only way to get both window id and tab id